# Shopify Liquid: Using 'if' statements to hide element on different pages

Tags: shopify, liquid

I placed this code into my collection.liquid template so that customers can choose by product types. It's working great!

```html
<ul class="types">
    {% for product_type in collection.all_types %}
  <li class="{{ product_type | handleize }}">{{ product_type | link_to_type }}</li>
 {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

However, I want to be able to "hide" this list after something has been selected. This is because after the customer chooses T-Shirts, it takes them to the T-Shirts page, which has a huge title of "T-Shirts" at the top, and, because of the code above, a smaller "T-Shirts" below it. Having a duplicate of the page title is annoying and I've been having trouble trying to figure out how to remove the  list after a product type has been chosen. I've tried this:

```css
ul.nothing { display:none; }
```

```html
<ul class="types" {% if page_title contains product_type %}class="nothing"{% endif %}>
    {% for product_type in collection.all_types %}
  <li class="{{ product_type | handleize }}">{{ product_type | link_to_type }}</li>
 {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

It's not working and I want to avoid having to do this manually

```css
body#t-shirts ul.types { display:none; }
```

etc...for all of my different product types.

Help!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you change

```
{% if page_title contains product_type %}
```

to

```
{% if page_title == collection.current_type %}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<li> {% for collection in collections %}
     {% if collection.products_count != 0 %}
     <br><a  href="{{ collection.url }}"> {{ collection.title }} <span class="count">({{collection.products_count}})</span></a>
{% endif%}  {% endfor %}  </li>
```

Comment: Here is how i fixed mine i hope it is super helpful to you